# j2me sprite not working

Tags: java-me, sprite

First, I'm sorry for my bad English. I'm a newbie J2ME

I wrote the below code after i watched some tutorial but it not working. I don't know what happen with it.

AnimationCanvas.java

```
package example;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.game.GameCanvas;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.game.LayerManager;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.game.Sprite;

public class AnimationCanvas extends GameCanvas implements Runnable {

    private Sprite ca;
    private int frameWidth = 14;
    private int frameHeight = 14;
    private boolean playing = true;
    private int a=1;

    public AnimationCanvas(){
        super(true);
        try {
            ca = new Sprite(Image.createImage("ca.png"), frameWidth, frameHeight);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        Thread runner = new Thread(this);
        runner.start();
    }

    public void run(){
        while (playing){
            drawDisplay(getGraphics());
            try{
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }

    public void drawDisplay(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(0x000000);
        g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
        ca.setFrame(1);
        ca.paint(g);
        flushGraphics();
    }

    public void stop(){
        playing=false;
    }
}
```

and AnimationMidlet.java

```
 package example;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
 import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;

 public class AnimationMidlet extends MIDlet {
      private Display display;
      private AnimationCanvas canvas;

      public AnimationMidlet() throws IOException {
           display = Display.getDisplay(this);
           canvas = new AnimationCanvas();
      }

      private void initialize() {                                         
           // write pre-initialize user code here

           // write post-initialize user code here
      }                            

      public void startMIDlet() {                                      
           // write pre-action user code here

           // write post-action user code here
      }                             



      public void resumeMIDlet() {                                       
           // write pre-action user code here

           // write post-action user code here
      }                              

      public void switchDisplayable(Alert alert, Displayable nextDisplayable) {                                            
           // write pre-switch user code here
           Display display = getDisplay();                                               
           if (alert == null) {
                display.setCurrent(nextDisplayable);
           } else {
                display.setCurrent(alert, nextDisplayable);
           }                                             
           // write post-switch user code here
      }                                   


      public Display getDisplay() {
           return Display.getDisplay(this);
      }
      public void startApp() {
           if(canvas!=null){
                display.setCurrent(canvas);
                canvas.start();
           }
      }

      public void pauseApp() {
      }

      public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
           canvas.stop();
      }

 }
```

and the output

Running in the identified_third_party security domain
java.io.IOException
Uncaught exception java/lang/NullPointerException.
    at javax.microedition.lcdui.ImmutableImage.getImageFromStream(Image.java:968)
    at javax.microedition.lcdui.ImmutableImage.(Image.java:939)
    at javax.microedition.lcdui.Image.createImage(Image.java:313)
    at example.AnimationCanvas.(AnimationCanvas.java:25)
    at example.AnimationMidlet.(AnimationMidlet.java:25)
    at java.lang.Class.runCustomCode(+0)
    at com.sun.midp.midlet.MIDletState.createMIDlet(+34)

Thanks for your reading!

Comment: Looks like it can't find the png file. Are you sure you've typed the correct filename? Try "/ca.png". If it still doesn't work, try loading ca.png in an image editor and save it again.

Comment: @mr_lou thanks you but it still doesn't work. can you give me example sprite class code. Thanks you very much

Comment: Make sure a valid ca.png file exists in the .jar root folder. If it is ca.PNG it won't do.

Comment: thanks @TelmoPimentelMota the problem happen with ca.png, i make new one and it work.